# How do I solve jerky freezes on Windows 7 x64 on an nForce 430?

Tags: windows-7, freeze, nvidia-nforce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to diagnose repeated freezing of windows 7 (comes back alive in few seconds)](https://superuser.com/questions/43389/how-to-diagnose-repeated-freezing-of-windows-7-comes-back-alive-in-few-seconds)

I haven't used my 64 bits Windows 7 for quite some time, and I'm starting to remember why.

Even under very low processor and graphics loads I'm experiencing fairly regular "jerky freezes", i.e., the computer seems to freeze for about half a second–audio and video halt and keyboard input gets delayed, but the mouse cursor keeps moving.
The same problem does not occur on Windows XP, Windows 7 x86 or Linux.
I've scanned for malware and looked if any processes jump out, but I can't find anything out of the ordinary.

Here are my system specs:

- AMD Athlon 64 X2 4200+
- ASUS A8N-VM CSM
- 4GB RAM
- 1 ATA drive, 1 SATA drive
- GeForce 9400GT

How would I go about tracing the source of such a problem?

**Edit:** it seems I have fixed the issue; see [my answer](https://superuser.com/questions/250504/how-do-i-solve-jerky-freezes-on-windows-7-x64-on-an-nforce-430/250524#250524) below.

Comment: @Moab: Do you mean [Wil's answer](http://superuser.com/questions/43389/how-to-diagnose-repeated-freezing-of-windows-7-comes-back-alive-in-few-seconds/43392#43392)? I have previously tried that without success. The issue seems to have been fixed as per my answer below, however.

Comment: No, But it should have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to have been resolved by installing the storage driver included with the [nForce Driver](http://www.nvidia.com/object/nforce_vista_win7_64bit_15.49.html) for my chipset, even though it is only officially supported with Windows Vista.

If this is not the case, I will reopen this question and look deeper into the other answers/suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Try [my answer here](https://superuser.com/questions/205298/windows-7-freezes/205307#205307) to troubleshoot freezes.